# A problem about Normal Subgroup in matrices.

Tags: group-theory

Let $$G=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} a & b  \\ 0 & c  \end{pmatrix} \mid c=a^{-1},a,b \in \mathbb R,a>0\right\}$$ and 
$$H=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & b  \\ 0 & 1  \end{pmatrix} \mid b \in \mathbb R\right\}.$$. I have proved that $H$ is normal in $G$. I've to show that $G/H \cong \mathbb R$. For proving that I have defined a homomorphism from $\phi\colon G\to \mathbb R$ by $\begin{pmatrix} a & b  \\ 0 & c  \end{pmatrix}\mapsto a-c$ so that ker($\phi)=H$.Is it correct?
 Also I've to find a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that $H\subsetneq N\subsetneq G$ or I've to show there is no such subgroup.
I don't know how to proceed to the last part.

Comment: The second part follows at once from the first, you have to consider the inverse image of any non-trivial proper subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$.  I think it works if one take the set of all the matrices in $G$ with $a= e^n$, n runs over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

No, $\phi$ is not a homomrphism. Instead of $\mathbb{R}$ let us consider the multiplicative group $\mathbb{R}_+=\{x\in \mathbb{R} |x>0\}$. Then the required homomorphism is $\begin{pmatrix} a & b  \\ 0 & c  \end{pmatrix}\to a$. Furter, $\mathbb{R}_+\cong \mathbb{R}(+)$ by $x\to \log x$ (thank to **Yassine Guerboussa** for his remark).

Comment: Dear Boris Novikov, I think the answer would be more direct if you compose your map with $\log$.  I don't understand $G/H \ncong \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Dear @Yassine Guerboussa, I want to emphasize that there is no isomorphism $G/H\cong \mathbb{R}$ independently on $\phi$. I think that in the problem there is an error.

Comment: @ Boris Novikov :The multiplicative group of positive (real) numbers is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ via the logarithm fuction

Comment: @Yassine Guerboussa You are right, thank you very much! I will correct the answer.

Comment: you welcome, thanks.